# Cannot get two SPAN elements in same line, no matter what

Tags: html, css

I have a table header where I have somewriting in the middle, and a previous and next button that I would like floated left and right. I have placed these in span elements. The Previous button floated left works fine, but the Next button floated right keeps going into the next row and I cannot get this fixed no matter what. I have tried `style="display:inline;"` on both spans, I have tried `style="white-space: nowrap;"` on the TH element, but no luck.

Here is my PHP output for the header row (it's all in one row, broken into multiple rows below for readability):

```
<tr>
    <th colspan="4">
         <span style="float:left;">$sPreviousTicket</span>
         $sTicketTask# $aProcess[id] - $aProcess[subject]
         <span style="float:right;">$sNextTicket</span>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Here is the resulting HTML on my page:

```
<tr>
    <th colspan="4">
        <span style="float:left;">
            <input type="button" onclick="window.location = 'view_request.php?process_id=207';" value="Previous">
        </span>
        Ticket# 209 - 3G
        <span style="float:right;">
            <input type="button" onclick="window.location = 'view_request.php?process_id=212';" value="Next">
        </span>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Comment: can you provide your css code? and also the width? it maybe an idea to use the element inspector as a helper.

Comment: That code [works](http://jsfiddle.net/Mrz3S/) as you're expecting it to so there must be some other CSS involved causing the issue.

Comment: Same as DAC84 here. Check the containing element's style.

Comment: Hi, thank you for all your quick responses. Unfortunately I do not have access to the CSS of this project and was hoping for a solution that I could overwrite the CSS inline. However, Dan's answer of just moving the text out to the end of the <TH> worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the "Ticket# 209 - 3G" line that's pushing it down.  Make that line last, like:

```
 <span style="float:left;">button...</span>
 <span style="float:right;">button...</span>
 Ticket# 209 - 3G
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I hate that HTML can be this temperamental.

Comment: You could probably put the Ticket text in some other container if you wanted to keep it in the middle.  Something inline would probably work.  But if it works just moving it to the end, that's all ya need.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following:

`span { display:inline-block; }`

Final HTML

```
<tr>
    <th colspan="4">
        <span style="display:inline-block;">
            <input type="button" value="Previous">
        </span>
        Ticket# 209 - 3G
        <span style="display:inline-block;">
            <input type="button" value="Next">
        </span>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Comment: This did not work, sorry. I tried in each SPAN and in a span that wraps everything else. Dan's solution worked.